# Hexa in string to file in java

Tags: java, string

I have String that contains hexa data. I wish to save it as raw hexa file.

So i have string like :

```
String str ="0105000027476175675C6261636B6772";
```

What i have to do , to get file.hex that will have same data in byte.

When i was trying that :

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream("c:/file.hex");
out.print(str);
```

i get file that have

> "0105000027476175675C6261636B6772"

but in hexa it is:

> 30 31 30 35 30 30 30 30 32 37 34 37 36 31 37 35 36 37 35 43 36 32 36
>   31 36 33 36 42 36 37 37 32

My goal is to have file that in hexa it will have

> 01 05 00 00 27 47 61 75 67 5C 62 61 63 6B 67 72

Comment: why dont u hack the string to include a space between 4 characters? u can do this via regex

Comment: What would adding a space possibly be good for? Read it again, @Wandang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hexa digits make a byte.

```
File file = new File("yourFilePath");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Now, loop through the string, taking two chars at a time using `string.substring()` method.

You would think `Byte.parseByte(theTwoChars, 16)` is a good option here, but it will fail miserably, because it thinks the byte is signed. You should instead use:

```
byte b = (byte) ( Integer.parseInt(theTwoChars, 16) & 0xFF )
```

You can either write the bytes one-by-one, or construct an array to store them in.

To write a `byte` or `byte[]` to your output stream:

```
bos.write(bytes);
```

Finally, close the stream:

```
bos.close();
```

---

Here's a fully working method I made to demonstrate it:

```
public static void bytesToFile(String str, File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {

        // check for invalid string    
        if(str.length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hexa string length is not even.");
        }

        if(!str.matches("[0-9a-fA-F]+")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hexa string contains invalid characters.");
        }

        // prepare output stream
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        // go through the string and make a byte array
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String twoChars = str.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2);

            int asInt = Integer.parseInt(twoChars, 16);

            bytes[i] = (byte) (asInt & 0xFF);
        }

        // write bytes
        bos.write(bytes);

    } finally {
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
assert str.length() % 2 == 0; // Two hexadecimal digits for a byte.
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
    String byteRepr = str.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2);
    byte b = Byte.parseByte(byteRepr, 16); // Base 16
    bytes[i] = b;
}

Files.write(Paths.get("c:/file.bin"), bytes, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
// Or use a FileOutputStream with write(bytes);
```

*(About terms: hexadecimal, coming from Greek, means 16, the counting base; one digit 0-9-A-F being able to represent 4 bits.)*

Comment: You sure about "byte.parseByte"? Shouldn't it be Byte? Also, your example needs Java 7, because of the Files class. Most people still use Java 6, so this is not advisable.

Comment: @MightyPork corrected Byte.parseByte; typo. Java 7 already is established in industry too, so as not to give archaic answers but enlightening ones, I try to use Java 7. Not at all sure though. _BTW your answer now is really fine. I would not have answered was it immediately given with code. But throw the `flush` into the toilet._

Comment: You mean like into the finally? Or delete it EDIT: nvm, google revealed the truth. Flush is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert your string to a short array and store this.